# Need help! SOT23 SMD transistor identify by marking FEQEQ

Tags: markings

Can somebody help me to identify SOT23 SMD transistor by marking FEQEQ[image]

Comment: What's the product? What's the schematic? What's the rest of the PCB? Might help to get some context here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an infineon IRLML6401PbF

Google IRLML6401 and look at the datasheet at the Bottom and look for "F". Because it starts with "F" its most definitely an IRLML6401